# mySQL: how to fill this questions - answers table

Tags: mysql

I have 5 tables

**Questions_Answers**

```
AID  |  QID  |  otherStuff  |  Username  |  UserID  |  otherStuff
```

**Users**

```
UserID  |  Username
```

**Node**

```
ID  |  Type  |  UserId
```

**Questions**

```
ID  |  oldQ_ID
```

**Answers**

```
ID  |  Question_Link
```

I have to **fill the empty table Questions_Answers** given the information in the other tables.

The **Question_Answer** table is supposed to contain, for each answer (row), the question it belongs to. Also, for each answer the username and userId.

The **Node** table contains both questions and answers. The Type field has 2 possible values 'question' and 'answer' specifying if that row is indeed a question or an answer. It contains the usedId who wrote the node.

In the **Questions** and **Answers** table, the ID fields are the **new IDs**.(I've imported these nodes in a new system). These are the IDs that should be added to the question_answer table (AID and QID fields, for answers and questions respectively).

In the **Questions** table, the oldQ_ID should be only used to assign the answers to their questions, and **not added** to the Questions_Answer table.

The Question_Link in the **Answers** table links each answer to its question and refers to the old ID of each question (oldQ_ID) (!).

One more thing. I need to insert the fields in Questions_Answers table in the correct fields, skipping the useless ones.

Thanks..

**Candidate solution:**

```
INSERT INTO node_comments (cid, nid, name, uid)
  SELECT a.nid, q.nid, u.name, u.uid
  FROM node AS n
  JOIN content_type_answer AS a ON a.nid  = n.nid
  JOIN content_type_forum AS q ON q.field_oldqid_value = a.field_qlink_value
  JOIN users AS u ON u.uid = n.uid
  WHERE n.type = "answer";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query needed to fill this table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379307/query-needed-to-fill-this-table)

Comment: it doesn't exist anymore

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any way to join the `Questions` or `Answers` tables to either the `Node` or `Users` table.  Have you included all the necessary columns?  Should there not be a question ID in the `Node` table?

Comment: You can use the ID field for the join. Both questions and answers are nodes and each node has an unique id in the Nodes table.  The IDs in Questions and Answers table are the same IDs you have in Node table.. probably this was the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
I've updated the answer to use `Node.ID` as the join relation for the `Questions` table.  I think this is close to what you are after, and it shouldn't be too tricky to change if it's not quite right:

```
INSERT INTO Questions_Answers (AID, QID, Username, UserID)
  SELECT a.ID, q.ID, u.Username, u.UserID
  FROM Node AS n
  JOIN Users AS u ON u.UserID = n.UserID
  JOIN Questions AS q ON q.oldQ_ID = n.ID
  JOIN Answers AS a ON a.Question_Link = q.oldQ_ID
  WHERE n.Type = "answer";
```

Here's what the query does:

1. For every row in `Node` where the `Type` is `answer`:

   - Compare `Node.UserID` with `Users.UserID` to find the matching rows from the `Users` table.
   - Compare `Node.ID` with `Questions.oldQ_ID` to find the matching rows from the `Questions` table.
   - Compare `Questions.oldQ_ID` with `Answers.Question_Link` to find the matching rows from the `Answers` table.
2. Select `Answers.ID`, `Questions.ID`, `Users.Username`, `Users.UserID` from the match in step 1, and insert these into the `Questions_Answers` table.

If you need to match `Node.ID` with an *answer* rather than a question, then you need a column like `Answers.oldA_ID` in the `Answers` table.  You cannot compare `Node.ID` with `Questions.ID`, as `Node.ID` is the old ID and `Questions.ID` is the new ID.

Comment: The otherStuff was just to specify I need to insert into specific fields. But it wasn't necessary, my fault. There is not question ID column in Node table. There is only 1 ID column and it is for both questions and answers. In case you are wondering, the ID field in the tables questions and answers has the same value you have in the node table.

Comment: @Mike: thanks. So.. you are looking for all questions in the Node table and adding all the related answers to the Questions_Answers table. Right ? I want all answers be added in the table Questions_Answers.

Comment: One more thing: the question's user is added to the questions_answers table instead of the answer's user. This is an issue, because I need the answerer instead :(

Comment: @Patrick: I've updated the `WHERE` clause to select answers instead of questions, which I think should solve the problem.

Comment: @Mike: 1) I wanted to tell you before, there is a misunderstanding: the Questions ID (the new id) are the same of Node ID. The old id matches only with the Question_Link values in the answer table. So the fifth line should be "JOIN Questions AS q ON q.ID = n.ID"... 2) If I just change the last line to type = "answer", and keep the fourth line (q.oldQ_ID = n.ID) I get an empty set because I'm filtering for only answers and looking for questions. I guess it is not correct

Comment: I think I've solved. I've wrote in my question the query... i will test for a while now...